# Can I use Mustache.js with Ember.js instead of Handlebar.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, mustache

Regarding these issues concerning the non compliance of Handlebar to Mustache specs:

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/425

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/745

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/816

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Mustache.js instead of Handlebar.js for data-mapping in Ember.